# How to reference controller string in HTML <img src>

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I am trying to display my controller string in the src of the img tag, but yes I am failing.

Here is my Model code:

```
public class PigeonDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int PigeonID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ring Number")]
    public string RingNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pigeon Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Pigeon Color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public string Sex { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Year Type")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Added")]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my Controller - Only the method i use:

```
[HttpGet]
    // GET: PigeonDetails/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var pigeonDetails = await _context.PigeonDetails.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PigeonID == id);

        string placeholder = _context.PigeonDetails.Where(u => u.PigeonID == id).Select(u => u.Image).ToString();
        pigeonDetails.Image = placeholder;
        if (pigeonDetails == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["ImagePath"] = pigeonDetails;
        return View(pigeonDetails);
    }
```

The pigeonDetails.Image is a string stored in the db (image path - and it stores correctly)

here is my html:

```
  @{var image = (PigeonDetails)ViewData["ImagePath"];}

 <img src="@image.Image" id="profile" alt="user" class="img-responsive radius">
```

It does not display my image on the page, please help.

Comment: try to set `ViewData["ImagePath"] = pigeonDetails;` just before the `return View(pigeonDetails);`

Comment: I did, yet no luck .

Comment: could you please show your full code of controller

Comment: There it is, i edited the post

Comment: did u specify any @model on top of view?

Comment: Yes @Pigeonmanager.Models.PigeonModel, all of the other stuff is displaying 100% except the img

Comment: then try this => `src="@Model.Image"`

Comment: <img src="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String]" id="profile" alt="user" class="img-responsive radius">

Comment: i did that is what i get when inspecting the page ... its not working

Comment: plz add your full view and model also

Comment: Will that help??

Comment: yes then i see exactly which is your model in your view and what you trying to pass in

Comment: are you referencing your view to any strangely type i.e.  `PigeonDetails` and does your top of view contains `@model ProjectNameSpace.Models.PigeonDetails`?

Comment: you can make quick fix like => 1) In your controller set `ViewBag.ImagePath = placeholder` and 2) from view your can use it like `src="@ViewBag.ImagePath"`

Comment: it gives the same output, the HTML does not see the controller string as its value but as an System.String

Comment: try to inspect your `img` in browser and let me know the html of `img`. try to keep above code in comment

Comment: this is what the html returns - <img src="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String]"

Comment: plz add `@model ModelNameSpace.PigeonDetails` on top of your view

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

upper page

```
@model ModelNameSpace.PigeonDetails
```

and your html element

```
<img src="@Model.Image" id="profile" alt="user" class="img-responsive radius">
```

Please change namespace. This is just example namespace name ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove string `placeholder` because pigeonDetails already has it if it matches the id. Also there is an issue with `.ToString()` on IQueryable as it will return  the fully qualified name of the runtime type of the object that received the call.

Second, Remove ViewData bit. You already have Model for your view (better if you use viewmodel instead).

Then add `@model PigeonDetails` on top of your view to expose Model property for your view.

Finally, `<img src="@Model.Image" />`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it. I removed a lot of unnecessary code.

I trimmed your `Edit` action method quite a bit:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
     if (id == null)
     {
          return NotFound();
     }

     PigeonDetails pigeonDetails = await _context.PigeonDetails
          .Where(m => m.PigeonID == id)
          .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

     if (pigeonDetails == null)
     {
          return NotFound();
     }

     return View(pigeonDetails);
}
```

In your `Edit` view page do the following:

```
@model YourNamespace.PigeonDetails

<img src="@Model.Image" id="profile" alt="user" class="img-responsive radius" />
```

Stay clear of view data, the preferred and safer way is to use a view model.

I hope this helps you.